# Regexp metacharacter followed by variables

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
var mystring = (parseInt(firstObject) + num).toString() + " 0 obj"
```

And would like to create a regexp that contains no digit before this string:

```
new RegExp(\D mystring, "g");
```

The above regexp doesn't work and I tried many things without success.

How can I do that?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. The value of "string" will always start with a number (or `NaN` I guess).  What do you want to match?

Comment: `string` is a keyword, please don't use it as a variable

Comment: @Pointy right but I want to find this string and make sure that no digit preceeds it

Comment: @ncohen how can a digit precede it? What does that even mean? The string will start with a digit (if "firstObject" and "num" aren't corrupted); where would any digits come from to precede it?

Comment: @hjpotter92 "string" is not a keyword in JavaScript.

Comment: Oh maybe I see - you want to use that generated string as the pattern, and you want it preceded by any non-digit character. Got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the correct code would be

```
new RegExp('^\\D' + mystring, 'g');
```

this works because `RegExp` creates a regular expression from a string.

Comment: Are you trying to find a string that doesn't start with a digit? What exactly are you trying to find?

Comment: make sure that mystring is not preceeded by a digit (but my string starts with a digit)

Comment: @Ferdi265 you'll need to double the backslash or else the regex will match an upper-case "D".

Comment: woops, sry, forgot that

Comment: Perhaps try the following: `var re = new RegExp('^\\D*' + mystring, 'g');`

Comment: woops, also forgot the assert start. Thanks hwnd

Comment: The leading `^` is necessary *if* the OP wants to search for his numeric pattern preceded by *one* non-digit at the start of the searched text. If it's intended to find the string *anywhere* in the searched text, then the `^` would not be needed.

Comment: it is needed. He explicitly said "no digit before this string"